# How do you tell the gender of a young rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, gender-differentiation

Someone wants to give us two rabbits about 4 months old, the say they are both girls; but I am not sure.  How do I tell the difference?

Comment: at 4 months the testicles should be easily detectable.  If they are there then its a boy.  Though they are still young enough that lack of them does not mean its a girl or fixed.  Ill work on a better answer with some images to help.

Comment: What makes you not sure they are both girls?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I volunteer at with two organizations that rescue rabbits [(see my profile}](http://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13/james-jenkins), 95% percent of the baby bunnies that come in are from pairs that were both the same gender when the rabbits were adopted unaltered. But somehow... well all the bunnies coming from the rescues I work with are spayed or neutered before going to their forever home.