# What causes rabbits to spontaneously change gender?

Tags: rabbits, biology, gender-differentiation

Working with rescued rabbits we often have people who purchased two girl (or boy) bunnies from a pet store or breeder, and a few months later they have a bunch of baby bunnies that need new homes.

I have heard this reported multiple times, in fact the majority of baby bunnies that enter the rescues in my area are the result of a spontaneous gender change of one of the rabbits.  According to Wikipedia it is known to occur with animals as complex as [chickens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_change), but it does not mention rabbits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [stated here](http://ezinearticles.com/?Can-Rabbits-Change-Gender-/-Sex?&id=5847031), they don't change gender.  Rabbits are one of those species whose gender is difficult to tell, especially in young animals, and therefore are regularly misidentified.

Comment: Related [How to tell sex and spay/neutered of rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6122/13)