# Do Rabbits Inbreed?

Tags: rabbits, breeding

I understand that rabbits quickly reproduce, but when a litter is born, is there a possibility that a male and a female from the same litter will reproduce?

Comment: +1 good question, surprised it was not asked sooner. You can tell from the **boldness** of my answer that I have some strong points to make on the topic. A significant percentage of bunnies needing homes, come out of not knowing the answer to just this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All rabbits in a family can and will interbreed, sons, daughters, mothers, fathers, grandparents, etc. When two unaltered (not spayed or neutered) rabbits of complimentary gender (boy and girl) are put together for even a few seconds, expect baby bunnies 28 days later.

There are many variables but expect rabbits to reach sexual maturity in 3 to 8 months [reference 1,](http://florida4h.org/projects/rabbits/MarketRabbits/Activity8_Maturity.html) [reference 2](http://www.bio.miami.edu/hare/spay.html).  Unless you are intentionally breeding rabbits, **consider 3 month old rabbits, old enough to make babies**.

Babies can be weened at around [6 weeks](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3108) if they are not separated or altered you can have a lot of rabbits in [a short time](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5877) If your are not able to **reliably** [tell the gender of your rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5878) they should be separated at 3 months old.

Speaking from experience, I can confirm that baby bunnies **are born** when two siblings of the **SAME GENDER** (*believed to be*) are left together. It is difficult to identify the gender of baby rabbits, and mistakes are often made. I volunteer with a couple of local organizations that take domestic rabbits, the majority of the babies that come in, come from just this scenario.