# My bunny had babies, what should I do?

Tags: rabbits, breeding

So I recently got a free bunny from someone that found it out in the street. When we received it my dad thought it was really big and could possibly be pregnant. We let it roam around the house freely and prepared a spot which serves as her toilet, but we noticed it would constantly go into my parents room in the closet where there is a bunch of clothes and had noticed some spots with missing fur and didn't know why until this morning.

It made like a nest with some towels and a bunch of fur, I saw something moving and they were babies.

I'm  not really sure what to do, should I leave them there where it's warm in the closet and let the bunny do her thing? Or put them in a box with towels and feed them? I'm guessing they're about 7 days old because they have fur but haven't opened their eyes yet.

Any information would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving the babies where they are is the number one thing to do, in the short term. Rabbits have been having babies (kits) for a long time, they are naturally good at it.

In the long term you will need to think about restricting the parts of the house the kits can get to until they have learned how to behave (i.e. what not to chew on. etc).  In the longer term you will need to think about separating them (see related [At what age can/should a baby rabbit (kit) be separated from its mother?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3108) and [Do Rabbits Inbreed?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6262))

I am assuming the rabbit you have is an escaped or abandoned house rabbit. Raising wild rabbits can be problomatic (see related [Can I make a baby wild rabbit a pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/854/can-i-make-a-baby-wild-rabbit-a-pet))

The area where mom is going to the bathroom needs a litter box, as does an area near the kits for their future use.

We have a couple of hundred questions with good answers about [house rabbits, take a look, there is lots to learn](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits)

If you have more questions about things that have not been asked yet, feel free to post a new question.